# ImportError: cannot import name 'DocToHtml' from 'robot.libdocpkg.htmlwriter' (C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\robot\libdocpkg\htmlwriter.py)

Tags: python, robotframework

I see this message after updating the robotframework version form 3.2.2 to 4.1.1
Maybe someone faced a similar issue and has a solution? I suppose it is somehow connected to another problem https://github.com/nokia/RED/issues/413

Here is Traceback:

```
  File "kubeless.py", line 23, in <module>
    from robot_hub import RobotHub
  File "c:\opt\robot\robot_hub.py", line 9, in <module>
    from rfhub import blueprints
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\rfhub\blueprints\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from rfhub.blueprints.api import blueprint as api
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\rfhub\blueprints\api\__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
    from . import keywords
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\rfhub\blueprints\api\keywords.py", line 7, in <module>
    from robot.libdocpkg.htmlwriter import DocToHtml
ImportError: cannot import name 'DocToHtml' from 'robot.libdocpkg.htmlwriter' (C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\robot\libdocpkg\htmlwriter.py)
```

kubeless.py

```
...    
from robot_hub import RobotHub
    ...
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        app.hub = RobotHub(app)
...
```

Comment: As mentioned below, RobotFramework 4.x is not supported but you can do the changes simply by replacing robot.libdocpkg.htmlwriter by robot.libdocpkg.htmlutils to import DocToHtml

Answer (score 1):

I found that package rfhub v 1.0.1  (https://pypi.org/project/robotframework-hub/) doesn`t support robotframework version > 4.0. There isn`t required method in htmlwriter.py